# GroupBy transform median with date filter pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, group-by

I have 2 dataframes:

df1:

| artist_id | concert_date | region_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2019-10 | 22 |
| 33322 | 2018-11 | 44 |

df2:

| artist_id | date | region_id | popularity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2019-10 | 22 | 76 |
| 12345 | 2019-11 | 44 | 23 |

I need to **add the median of the artist's popularity (which needs to be calculated only for the last 3 months before the concert and only for the same region)** from the second table to the first.

That is, the first table should look like (figures are invented, the point is not in them now):
df1:

| artist_id | concert_date | region_id | popularity_median_last3month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2019-10 | 22 | 55 |
| 33322 | 2018-11 | 44 | 44 |

Right now I'm using the following loop:

```
df1['popularity_median_last3month'] = pd.Series(dtype='int')

for i in range(len(df1)):
    df1['popularity_median_last3month'].values[i] = df2[(df2.artist_id==df1.artist_id.values[i])&(df2.region_id==df1.region_id.values[i])&(df2.date<=df1.concert_date.values[i])][-3:].popularity.median()
```

however, it takes too long with a large amount of data.

Please tell me how to avoid the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do this without a python loop:

```py
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['artist_id', 'region_id'])
df3 = df3[df3.date >= df3.concert_date - pd.DateOffset(months=3)]
df3 = df3.groupby(['artist_id', 'region_id', 'concert_date']).median().rename(
    columns={'popularity':'popularity_median_last3month'})
df1 = df1.join(df3, on=['artist_id', 'region_id', 'concert_date'])
```

Input:

```
df1
   artist_id concert_date  region_id
0      12345   2019-10-01         22
1      33322   2018-11-01         44
2      12345   2019-12-01         22

df2
   artist_id       date  region_id  popularity
0      12345 2019-10-01         22          76
1      12345 2019-11-01         44          23
2      12345 2019-11-01         22          50
3      12345 2019-08-01         22          68
```

Output:

```
   artist_id concert_date  region_id  popularity_median_last3month
0      12345   2019-10-01         22                          68.0
1      33322   2018-11-01         44                           NaN
2      12345   2019-12-01         22                          63.0
```

Explanation:

- Use `merge()` to create a dataframe with one row per `artist_id, region_id` tuple
- Filter this to contain only rows where the `date` (corresponding to the `popularity` data point) from `df2` is within 3 months of `concert_date`
- Use `groupby()` to get the median `popularity` for each `artist_id, region_id` tuple, and rename this column as `popularity_median_last3month`
- Use `join()` to add the `popularity_median_last3month` column to `df1`.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please consider marking the answer as "accepted".